# Object detection, faster-rcnn

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I have a problem when I try to generate tf.record. Although I have set train and test folders properly when I try to generate tf.record using this code,

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record
```

my train.record and test.record folders seem 0 kb.

[tf.record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrpov.png)
How can I fix that problem. Thank you for in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you generate .csv file properly? Might want to look at https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-your-own-object-detector-ad69dda69c85. there is a good flow on how to do it.